# Difference in use of the "present" and the "honorific present" (e.g. 하다)?

Tags: honorific

In the **해라체** (haera-che) speech level (which is a lower level as far as I understand), the present is **한다** (handa), which corresponds to the declarative present formal low form when looking for the conjugation of 하다 online. However, there is also the honorific present, which is **하신다** (hasinda) in the 해라체 speech level.

I used 하다 as an example, but this occurs for all verbs. While I understand the different formality levels, I don't understand the honorific/non-honorific choice within one formality level (e.g. 해라체 as mentioned above).

**When do Koreans use the non-honorific present tense 한다 and when do they use the honorific one 하신다?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's usually reasonably simple - you insert the (으)시 particle into a verb when the *actor of that verb* needs to be honoured. - e.g.

> 할머니께서 가신다

*Grandmother is leaving.*

A couple of things to watch for -

- Even if someone is superior to you, you might not honour them with (으)시 [if you are in the presence of someone who is, in turn, superior to *them*.](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/143/64)
- Some verbs have special honorific forms - for example, you wouldn't say '먹으세요' to talk about someone talking - you'd use 드세요 or 잡수세요 instead.

If you find it simpler (I do!), you don't need to imagine that there's an honorific form of each of the speech levels - I just think of it as using (or not using) the (으)시 particle.